# Calculating determinant of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A\in\mathbb K^{n,n}$

We choose $a$ columns and $b$ rows, where $a+b>n$. When a chosen row and column cross, the entry of matrix at that point is equal to $0$, for example:
$n=5$, chosen columns$=\{2,3,4\}$, chosen rows$=\{1,3,5\}$.

\begin{bmatrix}
q & 0 & 0 & 0 &t\\
a & s & d & f &g\\
z & 0 & 0 & 0 &b\\
y & u & i & o &p\\
h & 0 & 0 & 0 &m\\
\end{bmatrix}

Is determinant of such matrix always equal $0$?

From my observations it seems, that there always are at least $k+1$ rows with only $k$ values, so they can't be linearly independent. I don't know how to prove it though.

Comment: In your example, the first, third, and fifth row ($3$ vectors) span (at most) a $2$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^5$, and thus cannot be linearly independent.  Hence, the determinant is $0$.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote in the original post. If there are $k+1$ rows with $k$ values they can't be linearly indepedent (and then determinant is equal to $0$, as you said). But this is just an example, I wonder how to prove in general.

Comment: It matters where those $k$ values occur in the rows.  For instance, you have $3$ rows with $2$ values, but those $2$ values all occur on the same columns.  If the two values occurred on different columns I wouldn't be able to claim linear dependence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the determinant is defined by a sum over all permutations, you can show the value is $0$ if every permutation matrix (with one row chosen in each column to have a $1$, such that also every row has a single $1$) must have at least one entry $1$ in a position where $A$ has a $0$. To show that this is the case for any given valid choice of rows and columns and for every permutation is equivalent to showing that for any given permutation this happens for all valid choices (universal quantifiers may be interchanged).

Now fix a permutation matrix of size$~n$, and consider any choice of $a$ columns and $b$ rows, with $a+b>n$. This indirectly selects $a$ entries of the permutation matrix that are equal to$~1$ because of their column, and $b$ such entries because of their row. By the pigeonhole principle at least one such entry is chosen both because of its row and because of its column, so that the corresponding entry of $A$ is$~0$. QED

Answer (score 2):

Hint: By reindexing the columns and rows, we may assume that $A$ is in the form of
$$
A=\pmatrix{X_{(n-b)\times a}&Y_{(n-b)\times(n-a)}\\ 0_{b\times a}&Z_{b\times(n-a)}}.
$$
What is the maximum rank of $X$ (note that $a+b>n$)? What is the maximum column rank of $A$?